# Enum type prints out corresponding int

Tags: c++, enums

I have a class, `TakeEnum` that passes enum type `myData` data to another class `ADT` to store in a queue. Every aspect of the code works fine except for when i try to print out what was dequeued, before actually dequeuing it. Rather than print out what was actually dequeued, I get it's integer corresponding value from the switch statement. The programs runs fine except for this error.
Below are my codes.

```
main.cpp

enum myData{ONE, TWO, THREE};

char* myDataString(myData type)
{
char* s = "";

switch (type) {
case one:
    s =  "One";
    break;
case two:
    s =  "Two";
    break;
case three:
    s = "Three";
    break;
}
return(s);
}
```

Class that takes enum type has the following definitions:

```
TakeEnum::TakeEnum()
{

}

myData TakeEnum::GetData() const
{
    return myData(type);
}

myData::TakeEnum(myDatatype) : type(type)
{

}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& say, const TakeEnum& TakeEnumObj)
{
    say <<  TakeEnumObj.GetType();
    return say;
}
```

`operator<<` is a friend to `TakeEnum` class

In the stack and Queue class that takes myData Enum type, I have the following methods:

```
 ADT::ADT(int oSize, int sSize) : queueSize(oSize), stackSize(sSize), top(-1), rear(-1), front(-1)
    {
        queueArr = new myData[queueSize];
        stackArr = new myData[stackSize];
    }
```

Insert an enum type data into the queue.

```
bool ADT::Enqueue(myData type)
{
    if (IsQueueFull())
        return false;

    else if (IsQueueEmpty())
    {
        front = 0;
        rear = 0;
    }
    else
        rear++;

    queueArr[rear] = type;
    return true;
}
```

This method returns the element in front of the queue.

```
myData ADT::PeekQueue()
{
    if (!IsQueueEmpty())
        return queueArr[front];
    /*else
        return NULL;*/
}
```

This method should enqueue from the queue, but fail if Queue is empty.

```
void ADT::Dequeue()
{
    if (IsQueueEmpty())
        return;
    else
    {
        if (front == rear)
            front = rear = -1;
        else if (front == queueSize && rear == queueSize)
            front = 0;
        else
            front++;
        return;
    }
}
```

This is meant to push a single enum type data (myData) into the stack, but return false if stack if full.

```
bool ADT::PushShelf(myData aData)
{
    if (IsShelfFull())
        return false;
    else
    {
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = aData;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This piece of code should peek into and return the front element in the queue, then push into stack.

```
int ADT::InsertToStack()
{
    int i = 0;
    if (IsQueueEmpty())
        return i;

    if (IsStackFull())
    {
        cout << "Your stack is full.\n";
        return i;
    }
    while ((!IsQueueEmpty()) && (!IsStackFull()))
    {
        PushShelf(PeekOrder());
        cout << PeekQueue()";
        Dequeue();
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

When I run the code like this:

```
int main()
{
   ADT adt(10, 30);
   adt.Enqueue(one);
   adt.Enqueue(two);
   adt.Enqueue(three);

   adt.InsertToStack(); //This should cout one, but I get 1
   adt.InsertToStack(); //This should cout two, but I get 2
   adt.InsertToStack(); //This should cout three, but I get 3

   TakeEnum takeEnumObj;
   std::cout << myDataString(takeEnumObj.GetData()) ; //Nothing is displayed here

   cout << takeEnumObj; //overload from TakeEnum class, I get -858993460. I expect to have an enum data.
}
```

NOTE : This is an assignment.

Update:

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

changed

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& say, const TakeEnum& TakeEnumObj)
{
   say <<  TakeEnumObj.GetType();
   return say;
}
```

to

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& say, const TakeEnum& TakeEnumObj)
{
    say <<  myDataString(TakeEnumObj.GetData());
    return say;
}
```

Then I Peeked into stackArr to return a myData Enum type, which is then used to initialize `myData type` private data inside `TakeEnum::SetData()`. Therefore, `GetData()` will always have a to pass into MyDataString function. `std::cout << myDataString(takeEnumObj.GetData())`

Comment: I presume `operator<<` and `main` are defined in different files, right? Is `operator<<` declaration visible from `main`? How is it *declared*? Did you try stepping through your code with debugger?

Comment: `operator<<` is a friend to `TakeEnum` class

Comment: BTW, use `const char*` for literal string instead of `char*`

Comment: a stack and queue aren't the same thing. actually the opposite.

Comment: Your default ctor for the TakeEnum doesn't initialize its `type` member, so it has an arbitrary value and is accessing your name array out of bounds.

Comment: @self Yes I'm aware, but it's possible to implement both within the same class using different containers... If needed?

Comment: Isn't `int ADT::InsertToStack()` supposed to return `int` and `return i` does just that?

Comment: @alvits Yes it does. There is a print statement within the method that should cout the enum data that was first dequeued before pushing. If push fails, then it returns 0.

Comment: @Jarod42 , I can only work with `char* myDataString(myData type)`

Comment: @hello, Then don't return a pointer to memory that shouldn't/can't be modified. String literals are exactly that. Still, I'm fairly sure `const` should be added instead of the implementation being changed all around. That's very unfortunate that your assignment would require you to do that, and be aware that pointing to a string literal with `char*` is no longer valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
TakeEnum::TakeEnum()
{

}
```

Doesn't set `type` to anything, so

```
TakeEnum takeEnumObj;
```

has undefined `type` and

```
std::cout << myDataString(takeEnumObj.GetData()) ;
```

will only print usable output by dumb luck.

```
cout << takeEnumObj
```

resolves to printing the numerical value of `type`, which is some undefined value, -858993460 in this case.

As for printing out the enumerated value's name, sorry. Can't do that.

```
cout << PeekQueue();
```

will only print the numerical value. While you, the programmer, gets a nice pretty string to work with, the computer only sees a number. You would need to use your myDataString function to recover the name or create an array of strings that mirrors the enum values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the various bits of code you've dropped into the editor here

```
    cout << PeekQueue()";
```

is where you expect textual representations of the front of the queue - although obviously the pasted code doesn't compile.

You also reveal `PeekQueue` to be

```
myData ADT::PeekQueue()
{
    if (!IsQueueEmpty())
        return queueArr[front];
    /*else
        return NULL;*/
}
```

This returns a `myData`, and since you don't show an overload for `operator<<(ostream&, myData)`, this is why `cout << PeekQueue()` would print the enum value.

```
#include <iostream>

enum A { A1, A2 };
enum B { B1, B2 };

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, B b)
{
    switch (b) {
        case B1: os << "B1"; break;
        case B2: os << "B2"; break;
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    A a1 = A1, a2 = A2;
    B b1 = B1, b2 = B2;

    std::cout << a1 << ", " << a2 << ", " << b1 << ", " << b2 << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/EGSazW

Comment: here is my overload for `<<` : `ostream& operator<<(ostream& say, const TakeEnum& TakeEnumObj)
{
    say <<  TakeEnumObj.GetType();
    return say;
}`

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted suggests a connection between `TakeEnum` and `myData`.

Comment: You say "my overload for <<" but - see also http://ideone.com/C2mocF - you have to overload it for every type you want to have a custom outputter. Nothing in the pasted code suggests how you expect to get from `myData` to `myDataString`. If this doesn't answer your problem, I strongly suggest you produce an MVCE to demonstrate your problem succinctly with compilable code we can correct. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve